# Dynamic scroll area with expanding components

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page which has three divs inside a container div:

```
____________________
|------------------|
||   Expandable   ||
||                ||
|------------------|
|------------------|
||   scroll area  ||
||                ||
|------------------|
|------------------|
||    fixed       ||
||----------------||
|__________________|
```

The problem I have is that when the top div is expanded (by a javascript component), the scroll area is pushed down, outside of the container div, whereas i need it to dynamically contract. (fixed div is currently absolutely positioned, scroll div is pushed down beneath it)

It also cannot use fixed heights (e.g pixels) as it needs dynamically adjust to many different screen sizes.

video of problem: https://youtu.be/M-isVl1hs8Q

css:

```
.scrollcontainer{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
.floor{
  width:100%;
  height:100% - 60px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.item{
  flex:1 1 auto;
}

.broom{
  transition:1s linear all;
}
.dirt{
  transition:1s linear all;

}
.rug{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
}
```

javaqscript/html:

```
        <div className="scrollcontainer">
            <div className="floor">
                <div className="broom item">
                    <FoodItemList
                        foodItemList={[this.props.foodItem]}
                        user={this.props.user}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="dirt item">
                    <Scrollbars
                        autoHeight
                    >
                    <Comments comments={this.props.foodItem.comments} />
                </Scrollbars>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="rug">
                <Paper style={styles.paper} zDepth={0}>
                    <div className="leftcolumn">
                        <TextField
                            style={{color: 'white'}}
                            hintText="You can leave a comment here"
                            onChange={this.handleComment}
                            value={this.state.commentText}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="rightcolumn">
                        <IconButton
                            iconStyle={styles.smallIcon}
                            style={styles.small}
                            onTouchTap={this.addComment}
                        >
                        <ContentSend color={lightGreenA200} />
                        </IconButton>
                    </div>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would have been nice to see a non-working example. I think it's best to let those that answer decide what is helpful and what to omit from their analysis, rather than yourself.

Here's a quick codepen that I whipped up to show you the interactivity between the elements. It uses a `flexbox` for the space/size negotiation, an `absolute`ly `position`ed element, and a "`checkbox hack`" to emulate the javascript component. Throw on your desired `overflow` settings (not sure which direction of `scroll` or any of that jazz, or if you'll want a `wrapper`) and this will take care of the layout.

Here's the pertinent `flexbox` code:

I threw some names to visualize each counterpart to help convey the example's meaning.

In a sense, you're kinda sweeping some dirt underneath a rug!

```
.floor{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.item{
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 16px -4px red;
  flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

And relevant markup for that css:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="floor">
    <div class="broom item">
    </div>
    <div class="dirt item">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rug">
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to check the browser support for what's being used here!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBOwdw?editors=1100

Comment: thanks so much for your response, I have edited your example to fit mine, but unfortunately the problem persists. I have revised my question, adding the code currently in use and a video of the issue. Any advise you may have would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Terribly sorry, just noticed your comment. looking now. Will edit this with my response.

Comment: If you want further assistance, you should make a controlled demo/test-case that reproduces and exhibits the problem.